# How can I disable reCaptcha from my hpanel

Tags: authentication, logging, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, react-google-recaptcha

How can I disable reCaptcha from my hpanel if it not allowing me to login as admin of my website?
I am working on my site and the reCaptcha was not working and while I am trying to fix it I was mistakely logged out.

I have tried from to comment the reCaptcha out from the file and it now failed to reconise my user name and password.
I had expected it to just log me in again so that I can disable the reCaptcha pending when I can fix the problem.